# How is the INotifyPropertChanged event is handled in listener

Tags: wpf, events

Can anyone please explain me how is INotifyPropertChanged's PropertyChanged event is  handled in the listener(UI).

Thanks

Comment: Your question is way too vague... what aspect of it are you interested in?

Comment: An event listener can handle an event in any way it chooses.  Do you have a specific listener in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming you talk about binding, it checks for which property name the event was fired, get's the binding source object to see if it has such a property (via reflection), and if so gets the value and sets it to the bound target property. (This is a simplification)

Answer (score 0):

```
myObservableObject.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    var myObservableObject = (ObservableObject)s;

    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Name":    OnNameChanged(myObservableObject);    break;
        case "Address": OnAddressChanged(myObservableObject); break;

    }
});
```